# Negative values in Reportbuilder's TDBText's Display Format

Tags: delphi, delphi-7, reportbuilder

Using report Builder 7.x

I am trying to format a TDBText to display postive and negative dollar amounts in a 12 character field, left padded with zeros

example

000000001720
or 
-00000001720

I right click on my TDBText and choose display format and edit it to say:

000000000000;-00000000000

however, this does not work.

Actually the left side (Positive) works, but the right side (negative) does not.
I get characters trucated off the end. I lose the cents. The whole part gets rounded up.

actual values are:

-1671.56
-685254
193.15
4974.15

displayed values are:

-00000001672
-00000005853
000000000193
000000004974

displayed values should be:

-00000167156
-00000585254
000000019315
000000497415

what am i doing wrong?

Comment: When you type "does not work", you should immediately follow it with an explanation of exactly what that means. Saying something "does not work" gives us absolutely no information to go on in trying to answer your question. Please edit your question and explain in what way it doesn't work.

Comment: Sorry, i have edited the question, I hope it is better to understand?

Comment: You will probably need to multiply your values by 100 before displaying them. Try using a calculated field.

Comment: Yes, I Already did that!

Comment: I replaced the TDBText with a Variable component instead and added code. Works like a charm. I dont have enough credit to answer my own question for 8 hours, so if someone else colves it before hand - Great! Else, i will post my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I replaced the TDBText with a Variable component instead and added my own custom code. Works like a charm.